# Include partial site in Docpad

Tags: docpad

We have a Docpad-generated site with 'static' data. Another part of the site is build in another project using another technology.

Is there any way I can just include the latter files in the Docpad site? For example, depend on a module provided by the latter part?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case. I build the whole portal with docpad and small part of it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/raml2html.
http://gulpjs.com/ helps here. You can integrate it with docpad: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docpad-plugin-gulp

So you generate docpad site and then hook in to a proper docpad event (generateAfter) with your gulp task that takes your other files and places them in a proper docpad out structure.

Hope this overview is enough to give you an idea. If not, ask, I can try to help more